# Axis of symmetry of quadrics

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, quadrics

**METHOD TO FIND AXIS OF SYMMETRY OF QUADRICS**

Is there a general way to know how many axis of symmetry has a given quadric $Γ:x^tAx+2b^tx+a_{4,4}=0$ with associated $4x4$ matrix $$\overline{A’}= \begin{pmatrix} A & b\\\  b & a_{4,4} \end{pmatrix}$$ where $A$ is the $3x3$ matrix of the quadratic part and $b$ is the $3x1$ vector of the linear terms and $a_{4,4}$ is the constant term (maybe something that depends on the number of same eigenvalues, or on the number of non-null eigenvalues)? If there is, I would like to know the precise method, and how to obtain an equation for them (probably the direction-vector is determined by the vector that generates the eigenspace related to the axis of symmetry).

- If there isn’t a precise method but it is different for each quadric, is there a useful recap that summarizes how to find the axis of symmetry for each quadric?

**EXAMPLE OF FINDING THE AXIS OF SYMMETRY, FOR PARABOLOIDS**

For paraboloids, we know that they don’t have a center of symmetry, but they do have one axis of symmetry, which is the axis with, as a direction, the vector that generates the eigenspace ($V_0$) related to the null eigenvalue ($λ=0$). Then, we impose that the axis must contain the saddle point (in case of a hyperbolic paraboloid) or the “vertex” (is the name correct? I mean the minimum/maximum point of the paraboloid if it is not rotated) point (in case of an elliptic paraboloid).

But how do I know that there isn’t another axis of symmetry?

Comment: What does "symmetry axis of a quadric" mean?

Comment: @GerryMyerson sorry for the error, I corrected to “axis of symmetry”. Is it ok like this? Anyway, it’s the lines for which a quadric Γ is symmetric to. To do an example for conic sections: an ellipse/hyperbola has 2 axis of symmetry, a parabola has 1 axis of symmetry, a circle has infinite axis of symmetry.

Comment: So, we're talking about quadratics in three varaibles?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yes, since the matrix $A$ of the quadratic terms is a $3x3$ matrix

Comment: OK, so, you're setting this quadric equal to zero, and getting a sphere or ellipsoid or paraboloid or hyperboloid, and wanting to know how many axes of symmetry the surface has?

Comment: @GerryMyerson exactly. For the sphere I already know they’re infinite.

Comment: Does https://solitaryroad.com/c405.html help? or https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/about-us/departmental-art/quadric-surfaces or https://www.math.unl.edu/~gledder1/Notes/208/01-QuadricSurfaces.pdf

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks, but I already checked those links, and I don’t see there an explicit way to obtain the axis of symmetry of a quadric given its equation. And if axis of symmetry are mentioned, they’re mentioned in a “intuitive way”. I added more details to my question anyway to be even more precise.